# How to change desktop environment?

Tags: 17.10

Tengo instalado gnome Ubuntu y pienso cambiarme a Ubuntu 17.10 (que ya integra gnome por defecto); existirá algún comando para cambiar el escritorio de forma limpia y sin perder mis configuraciones.

**Translation: I have Ubuntu Gnome installed and I'm planning on changing to Ubuntu 17.10 that already has Gnome as default. Is there a command to cleanly change my desktop environment without losing all of my already established settings?**

Comment: Please ask concrete question on English. Many users speak english here.  You may want to use automatic translation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, you only need to make sure that all your packages are up-to-date, open *update-manager*, and start the release upgrade. That way you will automatically end up with Ubuntu 17.10.